# PHPUnit Symfony 1.4 url_for returning wrong URL

Tags: php, phpunit, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to create a unit test for a specific function that returns a given URL from a switch based on a set of params. Everything is fine until the return from url_for.

Here's the returned output:

```
http:///opt/ipc/bin/phpunit/phpunit/nikon-d7200-review
http:///opt/ipc/bin/phpunit/phpunit/nikon-d7200-review
http:///opt/ipc/bin/phpunit/phpunit/benq-gw2765-specs
http:///opt/ipc/bin/phpunit/phpunit/benq-gw2765-photos-2
http:///opt/ipc/bin/phpunit/phpunit/benq-gw2765-photos-2
http:///opt/ipc/bin/phpunit/phpunit/benq-gw2765-best-deals
http:///opt/ipc/bin/phpunit/phpunit/nikon-d7200-user-reviews
http:///opt/ipc/bin/phpunit/phpunit/canon-eos-7d-mkii-video-review
http:///opt/ipc/bin/phpunit/phpunit/best-mobile-puzzle-games_round-up
http:///opt/ipc/bin/phpunit/phpunit/best-mobile-puzzle-games_round-up
http:///opt/ipc/bin/phpunit/phpunit/best-mobile-puzzle-games_round-up
http:///opt/ipc/bin/phpunit/phpunit/best-mobile-puzzle-games_round-up
http:///opt/ipc/bin/phpunit/phpunit/round-ups/laptops
http:///opt/ipc/bin/phpunit/phpunit/news/wearables-fitness
http:///opt/ipc/bin/phpunit/phpunit/opinions/5-ways-the-humble-light-bulb-is-being-reinvented
http:///opt/ipc/bin/phpunit/phpunit/opinions/5-ways-the-humble-light-bulb-is-being-reinvented
http:///opt/ipc/bin/phpunit/phpunit/digital-cameras
http:///opt/ipc/bin/phpunit/phpunit/cameras
http:///opt/ipc/bin/phpunit/phpunit/info/evan-kypreos
http:///opt/ipc/bin/phpunit/phpunit/default/vitamix-s30
```

As you can see the returning URL has replaced the site URL with a PHUnit version. What I would like is a returned URL that is something more like this:

```
http://www.somesite.com/nikon-d7200-review
http://www.somesite.com/benq-gw2765-specs
http://www.somesite.com/benq-gw2765-photos-2
http://www.somesite.com/benq-gw2765-best-deals
http://www.somesite.com/nikon-d7200-user-reviews
http://www.somesite.com/canon-eos-7d-mkii-video-review
http://www.somesite.com/best-mobile-puzzle-games_round-up
```

I'm using the command line to run my tests.

If you need more information please say i'll do my best to explain further.

The function that is causing the issue is this...

```
url_for('@round_up?slug=digital_cameras', true);
```

AND my test script

```
    class Api2CompositionsHelperTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function setUp(){}
    public function tearDown() {}

    public function testUrlForItemType()
    {
        if(function_exists('url_for_itemtype')) {

            /**
             * Create stubs for function. itemType => params
             *
             * Params avaliable
             * - itemSlug
             * - absolute
             * - page
             * - pageTile
             * - itemIndex
             * - itemCategoryIdentifier
             */
            $stub = array(
                'itemType' => array(
                    // TODO: Find out if Preview is even being used.
                    // 'preview' => array(
                    //    'itemSlug'  => '',
                    //    'absolute'  => '',
                    //    'page'      => '',
                    //    'pageTile'  => '',
                    //    'itemIndex' => ''
                    //),
                    'review' => array(
                        'itemSlug'  => 'nikon-d7200',
                        'pageTitle' => 'image-quality-performance-and-verdict',
                    ),
                    'reviews' => array(
                        'itemSlug'  => 'nikon-d7200',
                        'pageTitle' => 'image-quality-performance-and-verdict',
                        'page'      => 2
                    ),
                    'review_specs' => array(
                        'itemSlug' => 'benq-gw2765'
                    ),
                    'review_photo' => array(
                        'itemSlug'  => 'benq-gw2765',
                    ),
                    'review_photos' => array(
                        'itemSlug'  => 'benq-gw2765',
                        'itemIndex' => 2
                    ),
                    'review_compareprices' => array(
                        'itemSlug'  => 'benq-gw2765',
                    ),
                    // TODO: Check recombu deals are still being used.
                    //'review_recombudeals' => array(
                    //    'itemSlug'  => null,
                    //    'absolute'  => null,
                    //    'page'      => null,
                    //    'pageTile'  => null,
                    //    'itemIndex' => null,
                    //    'itemCategoryIdentifier' => null
                    //),
                    'review_userreviews' => array(
                        'itemSlug' => 'nikon-d7200'
                    ),
                    'review_video' => array(
                        'itemSlug' => 'canon-eos-7d-mkii'
                    ),
                    'roundup|roundups|round_up|round_ups' => array(
                        'itemSlug'  => 'best-mobile-puzzle-games'
                    ),
                    'round_up_index' => array(
                        'itemSlug' => 'laptops'
                    ),
                    'news' => array(
                        'itemSlug' => 'wearables-fitness'
                    ),
                    'opinion|opinions' => array(
                        'itemSlug' => '5-ways-the-humble-light-bulb-is-being-reinvented'
                    ),
                    'category' => array(
                        'itemSlug' => 'digital-cameras'
                    ),
                    'root_category' => array(
                        'itemSlug' => 'cameras'
                    ),
                    'author' => array(
                        'itemSlug' => 'evan-kypreos'
                    ),
                    'default' => array(
                        'itemSlug' => 'vitamix-s30'
                    )
                )
            );

            // Loop through
            foreach($stub['itemType'] as $itemType => $params) {

                $itemType = explode('|', $itemType);

                foreach($itemType as $itemType) {

                    // Test all params
                    $route = url_for_itemtype(
                        array_merge(
                            array(
                                'itemType' => $itemType
                            ),
                            $params
                        )
                    );

                    // Check URL.
                    switch($itemType) {
                        case 'preview':
                            // See above TODO
                            break;
                        case 'review':
                        case 'reviews':
                            if(isset($params['page'])) {
                                $pattern = '^www.trustedreviews.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)review([a-zA-Z-]+)page([-0-9]+)^';
                            } else {
                                $pattern = '^http:\/\/www.trustedreviews.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)-review^';
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'review_specs':
                            $pattern = '^http:\/\/www.trustedreviews.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)specs^';
                            break;
                        case 'review_photo':
                        case 'review_photos':
                            if(isset($params['itemIndex'])) {
                                $pattern = '^http:\/\/www.trustedreviews.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)photos([0-9-]+)^';
                            } else {
                                $pattern = '^http:\/\/www.trustedreviews.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)photos^';
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'review_compareprices':
                            $pattern = '^http:\/\/www.trustedreviews.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)best-deals^';
                            break;
                        case 'review_recombudeals':
                            // See above TODO
                            break;
                        case 'review_userreviews':
                            $pattern = '^http:\/\/www.trustedreviews.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)user-reviews^';
                            break;
                        case 'review_video':
                            $pattern = '^http:\/\/www.trustedreviews.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)video-review^';
                            break;
                        case 'roundup':
                        case 'roundups':
                        case 'round_up':
                        case 'round_ups':
                            $pattern = '^http:\/\/www.trustedreviews.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)_round-up^';
                            break;
                        case 'round_up_index':
                            $pattern = '^http:\/\/www.trustedreviews.com\/round-ups\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)^';
                            break;
                        case 'news':
                            $pattern = '^http:\/\/www.trustedreviews.com\/news\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)^';
                            break;
                        case 'opinion':
                        case 'opinions':
                        $pattern = '^http:\/\/www.trustedreviews.com\/opinions\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)^';
                            break;
                        case 'category':
                            $pattern = '^http:\/\/www.trustedreviews.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)^';
                            break;
                        case 'root_category':
                            $pattern = '^http:\/\/www.trustedreviews.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)^';
                            break;
                        case 'author':
                            $pattern = '^http:\/\/www.trustedreviews.com\/info\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)^';
                            break;
                        default:
                            // TODO: research pattern for default
                            $pattern = '^http:\/\/www.trustedreviews.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)^';
                            break;
                    }

                    // Check pattern matches URL structure
                    $this->assertRegExp($pattern, $route);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->assertFalse(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a piece of your test code where you observe the problem?

Comment: You're probably using $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'] for generating the URL and that's what you get in cli mode. Anyway when asking, please show us the code that does not work, not only the output. And with a single URL is enough.

Comment: Sorry for the late the reply, I've edited the question and have narrowed it down to one function which is a core Symfony 1.4 function. I''l add my test code as well. I agree the CLI is using its own populated $_SERVER variables but how do I mimic what you'd get from live?

Comment: Look at the code of this function, analyze how it creates it's output, and then overwrite the info that you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, we did it to generate links in the sitemaps in CLI task, looks similar to what you need:

```
$context = sfContext::createInstance($this->configuration);
$context->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers('Partial');
$routing = $context->getRouting();
$routingOptions = $routing->getOptions();
$routingOptions['context']['prefix'] = '';
$routingOptions['context']['host'] = sfConfig::get('sf_host');
$routing->initialize($this->dispatcher, $routing->getCache(), $routingOptions);
```